# why do i get an exception starting springdata rest api

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, crud

Ive a little issue with my basic rest, crud api. My app works well but only when I dont have any field in my model which is object made by me. My video cassett model has Long id, String title and Genre genre and this genre is problematic. Genre has Long id, String title and String description. Unfortunately I cant post my casset using Json in postman because I want to send genre by its name. So I came up with the solution that I post CassetCreator instead of Casset. My CassetCreator is same as Casset but has genre which is String. So I post object, take its attribute and using jpa search genre by its name and then create Casset that I save manually. The problem is that when I do that, spring boot suddently throws exception that I cannot drop a table ... because it depands on ...
Any solution from the internet doesnt work for me, so I want to ask you.
Thanks in advance.

Models

```
import java.time.LocalDate;


@Entity
public class VideoCasset {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private LocalDate productionYear;
    @ManyToOne
    private Genre genre;

    public VideoCasset() {
    }

    public VideoCasset(String title, LocalDate productionYear, Genre genre) {
        this.title = title;
        this.productionYear = productionYear;
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public Genre getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(Genre genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public LocalDate getProductionYear() {
        return productionYear;
    }

    public void setProductionYear(LocalDate productionYear) {
        this.productionYear = productionYear;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Genre {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String title;
    public String description;

    public Genre() {
    }

    public Genre(String title, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

My problematic method

```
    @PostMapping
    public VideoCasset addCassett(@RequestBody CassetCreator cassetCreator) {
        String title = cassetCreator.getTitle();
        LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse(cassetCreator.getData());
        String genreName = cassetCreator.getGenre();
        Genre genre = genreManager.findByTitle(genreName);
        VideoCasset videoCasset = new VideoCasset(title, data, genre);
        return cassetVideos.save(videoCasset);
    }
```

and the exception

```
2020-03-18 17:18:42.869  INFO 2816 --- [           main] pl.hub.cassets.CassetsApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-18 17:18:43.458  INFO 2816 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-18 17:18:43.509  INFO 2816 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 44ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-18 17:18:43.908  INFO 2816 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8083 (http)
2020-03-18 17:18:43.915  INFO 2816 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-18 17:18:43.916  INFO 2816 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-03-18 17:18:44.007  INFO 2816 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-18 17:18:44.007  INFO 2816 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1088 ms
2020-03-18 17:18:44.095  INFO 2816 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-03-18 17:18:44.207  INFO 2816 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-03-18 17:18:44.212  INFO 2816 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:file:./bazaDanych2'
2020-03-18 17:18:44.379  INFO 2816 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-03-18 17:18:44.436  INFO 2816 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-03-18 17:18:44.525  INFO 2816 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-18 17:18:44.607  INFO 2816 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-03-18 17:18:45.066  WARN 2816 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "drop table genre if exists" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table genre if exists" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:241) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at pl.hub.cassets.CassetsApplication.main(CassetsApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Nie można skasować "GENRE" ponieważ zależy od "FK95K03D6B117EMKR21KIGQAUKA"
Cannot drop "GENRE" because "FK95K03D6B117EMKR21KIGQAUKA" depends on it; SQL statement:
drop table genre if exists [90107-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:576) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.ddl.DropTable.prepareDrop(DropTable.java:98) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.ddl.DropTable.update(DropTable.java:124) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:228) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted

2020-03-18 17:18:45.073  WARN 2816 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table genre (id bigint generated by default as identity, description varchar(255), title varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table genre (id bigint generated by default as identity, description varchar(255), title varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:439) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:314) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:156) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237) [hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at pl.hub.cassets.CassetsApplication.main(CassetsApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Tabela "GENRE" już istnieje
Table "GENRE" already exists; SQL statement:
create table genre (id bigint generated by default as identity, description varchar(255), title varchar(255), primary key (id)) [42101-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.ddl.CreateTable.update(CreateTable.java:89) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:228) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted

2020-03-18 17:18:45.086  INFO 2816 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-03-18 17:18:45.092  INFO 2816 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-18 17:18:45.368  WARN 2816 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-03-18 17:18:45.480  INFO 2816 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-03-18 17:18:45.627  INFO 2816 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8083 (http) with context path ''
2020-03-18 17:18:45.629  INFO 2816 --- [           main] pl.hub.cassets.CassetsApplication        : Started CassetsApplication in 3.12 seconds (JVM running for 3.966)
```

Comment: My guess is that you already have existing DB and did some changes in entity structure? Hence upgrade on it is unsucesfull?
If possible attach some logs and when execaly it's happening ( startup ?)

Comment: Sorry, just forgot about the logs but I uploaded it now

Comment: Try adding a field `List<VideoCasset> videoCassets` on `Genre`. Annotate it with `@OneToMany` and add `CascadeType.REMOVE` on that annotation

Comment: Unfortunatelly doesnt work :/ nothing changed, I get the same exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make a backup of whole database and then drop it ( or point to new database in your application properties)

Create it anew and let hibernate create whole table structures from scratch

From logs it looks like there was some previous structure with existing data

```
Cannot drop "GENRE" because "FK95K03D6B117EMKR21KIGQAUKA" depends on it
```

Hibernate failed to upgrade data structure to new one trying to drop some table with aready existing links and recreating it.

Comment: I tried it now and point to new database. The result is that it works once. Everything is ok but when I rerun, I face exactly the same problem

Comment: What do you have in ```application.properties``` ? In  ```spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto```  or ```hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto``` ? Cause it looks like you have ```create-drop``` there and with every run , hibernates tries to recreate whole structure. Set it to ```update``` and check

Comment: `server.port=8084
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./db11
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
`
Moreover I tried to use update, nothing changed

Comment: so on clean database with ```update``` on second run it stills throws exception ?

Comment: yes, but I found a little difference in stacktrace. Instead of 
`Cannot drop "GENRE" because "FK95K03D6B117EMKR21KIGQAUKA" depends on it` 
I got 
`Cannot drop "GENRE" because "FKGWYBALXJ55SKJKMXQX8V7AGIR, FK95K03D6B117EMKR21KIGQAUKA" depends on it;`
I dont know why but I cant "generate" the next dependency to genre, whatever I do , everytime I get those two chains of chars so I really dont know how it changed

Comment: well after db drop id's changed  . Try to name your genre entity table ```@Entity @Table(name="genres_table")
public class Genre```  or what thing more thing I can think of is changing hibernate.dialect

Comment: when I do that I get same exception and to make things worse some new errors like: `Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK95K03D6B117EMKR21KIGQAUKA: PUBLIC.VIDEO_CASSET FOREIGN KEY(GENRE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.GENRE(ID) (196)"; SQL statement:
 `
Then I also added `@Table` annotation to cassetts and I came back to the previous situation...

Comment: very odd...try to maybe change hibernate.dialect to Hibernate5  ?

Comment: Jesus, I found the solution, the problem was that I had various strange files in my priject structure like db12.mv.db, bazyDanych.mv.db, db11.mv.db ,db12.trace.db, bazyDanych.trace.db, db11.trace.db. When I deleted it all and then rerun - everything is working. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate that!!

Ive run it lot of times and nothing crashed. To be honest I dont know why but it works!

Comment: Glad you found culprint :) BTW recommend to work on some docker with psql or mysql container - way easer to maintain while developing